How to simply understand a segment size and build off of it
This is a basic question of Geometry Nodes.  Erindale answers this here: Instance on Edges with Geometry Nodes - Blender 4.1 Tutorial, but some of the info is outdated, and its FAR to complex of a tutorial.  That is, to understand how to do it, you have to watch like 3 videos, and success in following exactly is really hard given that some of the nodes are outdated.
I am trying to create a standing-seam metal roof.  To do this, I need to grab a segment from a trapezoid, measure it, build a curve off of it, and extrude it equal to the distance of another segment. Can someone help with this?


I don't see a trapezoid in your question other than the rectangle connecting two triangles. You want to measure one of its edges? It's not clear what you want to do, what you're struggling with. Take a look on highly rated questions to get a feel how to use this website, open-ended start-of-discussion posts are better posted on websites like https://blenderartists.org/

The trapezoid is the roof structure.  If looked at from a top down perspective, you'd see a trapezoid.  As a 3d structure, I guess you are correct - its a rectangle and 2 triangles.  I am looking to read the length of line A, create a curve equal to its length, and extrude a profile along line B (length of B) similar to what you see in the roof picture.   Then, do it again for Line C, the length of D.

I understand the part with A and B as : "starting with JUST lines A and B, I want to extrude line A along line B to create the rectangle".  But I have to admit that I do not understand the part with lines C and D. Do you start with both lines, C and D ? Because if the rectangle is created before, there is nothing new to add, except to fill the triangular face...

Try to use the visual of the roof as a guide to help understand.  Think large sheets of metal.  The segment A could take on a "ribbed" profile.  Then extrude the profile along B to make the middle section.   Now for C.  C also has a ribbed profile, and maybe extrudes along D.  I say "maybe because Im not sure how to recreate the image. I kind of think of the triangular part of the roof to be like a loft, where C runs along D and B.  But, a loft would cause the "ribbed" part of the roof to get smaller as C lofts upwards - which is not the desired effect.
